# NLTK Brill-Tagger exits after 2.5h with exit code 137. What is wrong?

Tags: python, zsh, nltk

I want to tag some text with the Brill-Tagger from NLTK. However, the script exits like this:

```
$ ./brill.py
Training Brill tagger on 43005 sentences...
Finding initial useful rules...
zsh: killed     ./brill.py                                  137
```

Googling for the exit code 137 only shows that bash has an exit code 137 which means

```
Exit code 137: The job was killed because it exceeded the time limit.
```

When I check for limits by calling limit I get the following output and I guess the exit codes are not equivalent:

```
$ limit
cputime         unlimited
filesize        unlimited
datasize        unlimited
stacksize       8MB
coredumpsize    0kB
memoryuse       unlimited
maxproc         30973
descriptors     1024
memorylocked    64kB
addressspace    unlimited
maxfilelocks    unlimited
sigpending      30973
msgqueue        819200
nice            0
rt_priority     0
rt_time         unlimited
```

Another thing is that the script only runs for like two and a half hours:

```
$ date && while [1];do if [[ -z `ps -C brill.py | grep brill.py` ]]; then; date;break;fi;done
Mo 20. Aug 19:54:52 CEST 2012
Mo 20. Aug 22:30:40 CEST 2012
```

So my questions are:

- Where are zsh exit codes documented?
- What does 137 mean?
- How can I keep this process alive?

*Edit*: Additional infos

- **OS**: Debian with Gnome: `Linux debian 3.2.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 28 09:07:26 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- **Zsh**: `zsh 4.3.17 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)`
- **NLTK**: `2.0.1`
- **Python**: `Python 2.7.3rc2`

Comment: What system are you running the program on?

Answer (score 1):

Status 137 means that he has been killed by signal 9 (137 = 128 + 9), which is an unblockable kill signal.
It doesn't have to be the reason you found (time limit).

If your script launches some process frequently, maybe the maxproc limit is reached after 2.5 h?
Maybe it takes too much memory and oomkiller starts? Check the output of `free -m` regularly.

Try to use `ulimit -c unlimited` before launching the program.

Comment: I tried it with no limit for the coredump size and I monitored the memory-usage. You were right, the memory is declining linear. I think this is related to the size of my training-set for the brill-tagger and I am trying to find a maximal size for that one now. Also I mailed this topic to the nltk-users Google Group. Hey you guys :)